# how to create a java program that can't be closed on window and mac os

Tags: java

basically I want to create a program that can't be closed or minimised unless the right button is clicked. I am doing this for an educational purpose. this program can't be closed unless i want it to be closed is there any way to di it with java?

Comment: "educational" sounds much more like "nefarious" given the description of this functionality.

Comment: @renan gado You first use what they said to Do nothing on close then you must use the Robot class to release certain keys so they can't press them and then you must kill explorer process and run a loop checking for task manager to kill it also. I have a program that does this for 5 seconds or so.

Comment: A robust solution would require using tools beyond what core Java has to offer and I suggest that you search on the term "Java kiosk program". or kiosk application. Any solution would be OS dependent, making your question too broad (and a reason to close this question).

Comment: @3kings i didn't understand the kill explorer process can you explain me what did u mean sorry im kind a beginner haha thanks

Comment: Yeah so "explorer" is pretty much in simple terms the windows desktop. so  it would close it and then your task bar will not show up so you can't simply right click the java program and click exit.

Comment: cool thanks for your help i will try to implement that because I had no ideia how to start

Comment: @3kings can you please explain how do i kill explore process with java or in cmd because im looking for it and can't find anything. thanks

Comment: @3kings taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe would it work? its that what u meant?

Comment: @3king i managed to do thanks

Comment: @renangado yes that is what i meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using swing, you can use `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` which prevents the window from closing.

Answer (score 1):

Every program can be closed with the use of task manager on any operating system, otherwise you can do it like this if you are dealing with swings:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING);
```

Comment: This is simply not true as there certainly *are* ways to create un-closeable kiosk programs for Windows. The solutions would require going beyond core Java of course, but they are available.

Comment: Correction: "for any operating system"